# Nested list comprehension for numpy

Tags: python, numpy, list-comprehension

I have an issue that I can't seem to resolve.

I am building in a numpy array of shape (100, 30) from lines of a file (100 lines of 30 values each), and I need to make this array into a shape (100, ) with as values the mean of the *n* last values from each line of the original array.

I have as a goal to do this in one line, so I tried nested list comprehensions but I feel totally lost in there and I'm not sure of what I am doing.

This is what I got so far, this gives me a correctly shape array but with (I believe) the wrong values.

```
def perf_n_last(n):
    a = np.array([np.mean([i for j in range(len(i)-1, len(i)-(n+1), -1)]) for i in np.loadtxt('myfile.txt')])
    print(a.shape) #outputs (100, )
```

The input and output should look like:

```
input_f = [[1. 2. 3. 4. 5.]
           [2. 3. 4. 5. 6.]
           [3. 4. 5. 6. 7.]]
#We assume n = 2
output_f = [4.5 5.5 6.5]
```

I am also open to suggestions about list slices. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Could you share a smaller sized data sample and an expected output so it can be reproduced?

Comment: Why would you demand this to only use up one line? What you have is much less easily legible than it would be if you were to unwrap it.

Comment: Why not just make the (100,30) array from the file then take its mean ?

Comment: @acdr you are totally right, it was a challenge from a classmate and not a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, this can actually be done very quickly with numpy, assuming each row in the 2d array is the same length:

```
def perf_n_last(n):
    return np.loadtxt("myfile.txt")[:,-n:].mean(1)
```

which loads the file, slices to include all rows but only the `n` last columns, and takes the mean of each resulting row.

Comment: Thank you very much, I got carried away by list comprehensions and didn't see this solution

Comment: Can't you just write `np.mean(np.loadtxt("myfile.txt")[:,-n:])`?

Comment: @Bazingaa, that will take the overall mean of the array rather than the mean of each row.

Comment: @mackenziedg: You can pass `axis=1` I think for the row wise mean